# The service "redirect.request_subscriber" has a dependency on a non-existent service "path_alias.manager"

Tags: dependency-injection

We have inherited a Multisite Drupal setup and are managing the migration for a client. We have the codebase set up locally and have two of the sites up and running. We are hitting an error on the third though:

> Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: The service "redirect.request_subscriber" has a dependency on a non-existent service "path_alias.manager". in Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass->processValue() (line 86 of /Users/{hidden}/Sites/{hidden}/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php).

We're not sure why this error is displaying on this one site and not on the others. Can anyone help please? Drupal core is up to date - running 9.3.12.

Comment: Is the `path_alias` module enabled? https://www.drupal.org/node/3092086

Comment: I cannot access this particular site's admin (the whole site is erroring), but running `drush pm-list --type=Module --status=enabled` tells me that the module is enabled.

Comment: ... however, the fact that the `path_alias` and `path_alias_revision` database tables do not exist for this site suggests otherwise!

Comment: Then the database is not in syn with the codebase. You can try if update.php can fix this, but if there is such a big gap I doubt it works. If you can't log in anymore you can grant access to update.php in settings.php

Comment: I'd uninstall the module in question and then enable it so it goes through the installation process properly. I've seen this happen before but never worked out why, but turning it off and on again :) seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thank you all. @4uk4 accessing update.php revealed what appears to have happened. The previous development team went through an exercise of updating all the sites to Drupal 9 before handing them over to us. It would appear that they missed a couple!

Answer (score 0):

For me, a search and replace in the .sql file changed path_alias.manager data entries unwanted ... so needed to get my data back right ..